# Is it possible to spawn a Thaumcraft 4 hungry node in creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I'm doing some experiments in creative mode to determine if it's possible to energize a Thaumcraft 4 hungry node without converting it to a tainted node. I've seen people posting that they managed to accomplish this using AE2 formation planes in conjunction with stabilizers / transducers and redstone blocks, but I've been unable to duplicate what they've done in survival mode.

Hungry nodes are .. well, kind of rare, at least from the perception of someone deliberately trying to find one. In creative mode, a player can spawn a random aura node, but I've been unable to spawn a hungry node despite hundreds of attempts.

From what I can tell from the wikis (FTB/Thaumcraft 4) - there's no preferential biome for these to spawn. They just .. occasionally happen.

Is there anything I can do to deliberately spawn one of these in creative mode so I can experiment, or at least increase my chances (biome placement / etc)?

Comment: I have spent quite a bit of time trying to find one that generated in the world without luck, which led me to trying this.

Comment: You can spawn a hungry node in a jar with a /give command. http://thaumcraft-4.wikia.com/wiki/Commands contains all the info you need, if I don't forget I'll turn it into a proper answer tonight.

Comment: @TimPost If you have twilight forest mod it is a great place to find hungry nodes because of the huge number of nodes there. This is if you don't want to cheat in survival.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `/give` command to spawn jarred nodes with specific NBT data, like this command, which gives a player a jarred hungry node with 100 terra:

`/give <player> Thaumcraft:BlockJarNodeItem 1 0 {nodetype: 4, Aspects:[{amount:100, key: "terra"}], nodeid: "0:0:0:0"}`

Simply place the jar in the world and unpack it like you would any other node.

In some cases your command will be too big to fit into the chat bar; I suggest using a command block to give the node to the nearest player (using the `@p` target specifier) if you run into that.

There are four tags that control the behavior of the spawned node:

`nodetype` determines what type of node it is, and ranges from 0 to 5.

0. Normal
1. Unstable
2. Sinister
3. Tainted
4. Hungry
5. Pure

`nodemod` determines whether it's a bright, pale, or fading node. If it's omitted, the node is normal.

0. Bright
1. Pale
2. Fading

`Aspects` is an array of aspects that the node has; it's defined like this:

```
Aspects:[{amount:<amount>, key:<aspect>},{amount:<amount2>, key:<aspect2>}]
```

Keys are the lowercase names of the aspects; amount is the amount of vis the node has of that type. For example, to make a node with 100 of each primal aspect, your Aspects tag should look like this:

```
Aspects:[{amount:100, key:"terra"},{amount:100, key:"aqua"},{amount:100, key:"perditio"},{amount:100, key:"ordo"},{amount:100, key:"ignis"},{amount:100, key:"aer"}]
```

I can't find anything on `nodeid` unfortunately, so I can only speculate on it. It appears to be information about where the node was when it was jarred, in the form `dimension:x:y:z` - you should be fine just leaving it at `0:0:0:0`.

The bulk of this information was sourced from [this Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/feedthebeast/comments/2qzo7a/is_there_a_command_to_spawn_a_node/cnb2qcv) and [this page on the Thaumcraft 4 Wikia](http://thaumcraft-4.wikia.com/wiki/Commands#Specific_Node_Spawning).

Comment: Aha, it was buried there (well, not really buried, just not really surfaced) which is why it eluded me. It would seem that a command block is the best option for those wanting to experiment (or just build traps in adventure maps). Now if only I could create a Mystcraft age built entirely of crafting tables ...

Comment: Thanks for making this post, I forgot to do it after I posted the wikia link